# Yii2 pjax, как при сабмите сохранить добавленный Jquery по клику класс элемента

Tags: yii2, pjax

Суть такова, что имеются блоки с чекбоксами, при клике на блок к нему добавляется класс active, при этом по остальным блокам проходит проверка на наличие этого же класса и в случае удачи удаляем его. Таким образом класс active одновременно может быть только у одного блока. Но при чеке какого-либо чекбокса происходит естественно перезагрузка pjax DOM элементов и класс active исчезает. Как можно запомнить и передать этот класс этому элементу после pjax перезагрузки?

Сначала была такая идея

```
function collapse(){
        $('#filter-form [type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $(this).closest('#filter-block').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
$(document).on('pjax:success', function(e) {
        collapse();
    });
```

Но так класс добавляется всем блокам с выбранными чекбоксами, а нужен только тот с которого был сабмит.

Собственно сама кликалка

```
$('body').on('click', '#filter-title' , function(){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
```

Может к сабмиту как то прикрутить? Так не работает:

```
$('body').on('change', '.checkbox__filter', function (e) {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
       $(this).closest('#filter-block').addClass('active');

    });
```

Comment: Как вариант сохранять индекс элемента перед pjax-запросом и после перезагрузки искать элемент по этому индексу и делать его активным

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka Да, в итоге так и поступил.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос добавив по клику запись индекса элемента (via .index()) в скрытый инпут

```
var $set = $('#filter-title'),
            n=$set.index(this); 
    $("input[name=index]").val(n);
```

Затем после обновления DOM, по этому индексу ищем нужный элемент и добавляем ему нужный класс.

```
var eq = $("input[name=switch]").val(); 
    $('#filter-title:eq('+eq+')').parent().addClass("active");
```